# use tablename different than slug

Tags: bolt-cms

I am buliding a single-language website (german) but like to have my code/tables etc. in english.
When I define a contenttype like so:

```
plays:
    name: Theaterstücke
    slug: theaterstuecke
    tablename: plays
    singular_name: Theaterstück
    singular_slug: theaterstueck
```

bolt uses the table bolt_plays but in twig I have to use ....records = "theaterstueck/latest/6". But I would like to have the template use english routes ("play/latest/6") and the URL still http://example.com/theaterstuecke

Do I have to use translations and routing or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

Change both slugs to :

```
plays:
    name: Theaterstücke
    slug: plays
    tablename: plays
    singular_name: Theaterstück
    singular_slug: play
```

And it should be fine

Comment: oh sorry, i misunderstood the question ... There's no other way, then :)